ASP.NET Core Identity and Microsoft Graph integration: issues with token expiration
We have an ASP.NET Core web application with two authentication flows:

ASP.NET Core Identity for standard user authentication
External authentication using Microsoft 365

We're working on a new feature that allows users to send emails through Microsoft Graph when they sign in using the external Microsoft 365 authentication. We are using delegated permissions for this, storing Microsoft Graph tokens in a SQL database instead of the memory cache to avoid losing them during application restarts or crashes.
The external login flow works as expected, and users can successfully send emails via Microsoft Graph, however, after some time the Microsoft Graph token is removed from the database, even though the user is still logged into the application. As a result, sending emails fails with a token missing related error.
I wasn't expecting that behaviour, I though there was a sort of automatic token refresh behind the scene. Also when this exception happens the user is still logged in.
Has anyone encountered a similar issue or have suggestions for resolving this issue? Any insights or advice would be greatly appreciated. Below is the relevant code we've implemented so far for reference.
appsettings.json configuration:
"AzureAd": {
    "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
    "Domain": "[Enter the domain of your tenant, e.g. contoso.onmicrosoft.com]",
    "CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc",
    "SignedOutCallbackPath": "/signout-callback-oidc",

    "IsEnabled": true
},
"MicrosoftGraph": {
    "BaseUrl": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0",
    "Scopes": "mail.send"
},

Startup.cs code:
services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
    .AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
    .AddErrorDescriber<CustomIdentityErrorDescriber>();

services.Configure<IdentityOptions>(options =>
{
    // Password settings
    options.Password.RequireDigit = true;
    options.Password.RequiredLength = 8;
    options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = true;
    options.Password.RequireUppercase = true;
    options.Password.RequireLowercase = true;

    // Lockout settings
    options.Lockout.DefaultLockoutTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromHours(8);
    options.Lockout.MaxFailedAccessAttempts = 10;
    options.Lockout.AllowedForNewUsers = true;

    // User settings
    options.User.RequireUniqueEmail = false;
});

services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(config =>
{
    config.LoginPath = "/Home/Login";
});

services.AddDistributedSqlServerCache(options =>
{
    options.ConnectionString = connectionString;
    options.SchemaName = "dbo";
    options.TableName = "TbDistributedTokenCache";
});

services.AddSession(options =>
{
    options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(20);
    options.Cookie.HttpOnly = false;
    options.Cookie.IsEssential = false;
});

try
{
    var conf = Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd");

    if (conf != null && Boolean.Parse(conf["IsEnabled"]))
    {
        var credentials = GetAzureAuthCredentials();

        if (credentials != null)
        {
            var initialScopes = Configuration["MicrosoftGraph:Scopes"]?.Split(' ');
            services.AddAuthentication()
                    .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(opt =>
                    {
                        opt.ClaimActions.MapAll(); 
                        opt.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;
                        opt.ClientId = credentials.ClientId;
                        opt.TenantId = credentials.TenantId;
                        opt.ClientSecret = credentials.ClientSecret;
                        opt.CallbackPath = conf["CallbackPath"];
                        opt.SignedOutCallbackPath = conf["SignedOutCallBackPath"];
                        opt.Domain = conf["Domain"];
                        opt.Instance = conf["Instance"];

                    }, cookieScheme: null 
                                          // Solves cookieScheme conflict with default aspnetcore identity cookiescheme
                                          //https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-identity-web/issues/133

             )
            .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi(initialScopes)
            .AddMicrosoftGraph(Configuration.GetSection("MicrosoftGraph"))
            .AddDistributedTokenCaches();
            services.AddScoped<IO365Manager, DelegatedO365Manager>();

        }
    }

}
catch (Exception) { }

DelegatedO365Manager class:
public class DelegatedOffice365Manager : IOffice365Manager
{
    private readonly GraphServiceClient _graphClient;

    private Recipient[] ParseRecipients(string recipientString)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(recipientString))
        {
            return Array.Empty<Recipient>();
        }

        return recipientString
            .Split(new[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
            .Select(email => new Recipient
            {
                EmailAddress = new EmailAddress
                {
                    Address = email.Trim()
                }
            })
            .ToArray();
    }

    public DelegatedOffice365Manager(GraphServiceClient graphClient)
    {
        _graphClient = graphClient;
    }

    public async Task<(bool Success, string ErrorMessage)> SendEmailAsync(Office365EmailMessage email)
    {
        try
        {
            var message = new Message
            {
                From = new Recipient
                {
                    EmailAddress = new EmailAddress
                    {
                        Address = email.FromAddress
                    }
                },
                Subject = email.Subject,
                Body = new ItemBody
                {
                    ContentType = BodyType.Html,
                    Content = email.BodyContent
                },
                ToRecipients = ParseRecipients(email.ToRecipients),
                CcRecipients = ParseRecipients(email.CcRecipients),
                BccRecipients = ParseRecipients(email.BccRecipients),
            };

            await _graphClient.Me
                .SendMail(message, email.SaveToSentItems)
                .Request()
                .WithAuthenticationScheme(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .PostAsync();

            return (true, string.Empty);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return (false, ex.Message);
        }
    }
}

Controller action method:
[AuthorizeForScopes(Scopes = new string[] { "mail.send" }, AuthenticationScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]
public async Task<JsonResult> SendMailWithOffice365(O365EmailMessage email)
{
    if (_o365Manager == null)
    {
        return new JsonResult(new { statusCode = -1, message = "Graph client not initialized" });
    }

    if (User.GetMsalAccountId() == null)
    {
        return new JsonResult(new { statusCode = -2, message = "User not authenticated with Office 365" });
    }

    var result = await _o365Manager.SendEmailAsync(email);

    if (result.Success)
    {
        return new JsonResult(new { statusCode = 0, message = "OK" });
    }
    else
    {
        return new JsonResult(new { statusCode = -3, message = result.ErrorMessage });
    }
}

JavaScript code:
function sendMailW365(params) {
    // Define the URL endpoint for sending mail with Office 365
    let url = baseUrl + 'api/data/SendMailWithOffice365';

    $.ajax({
        url: url, 
        data: params, 
        headers: { 'x-ReturnUrl': '/' }, 
        type: "POST", 
        cache: false, 
        contentType: 'application/json', 
        
        success: function (response) {
            let statusCode = response.statusCode; 
            let message = response.message; 

            // Handle different status codes
            switch (statusCode) {
                case 0:
                    // If status code is 0, mail was sent successfully
                    appendMessage('Send Mail', 'E-Mail sent successfully!', 'INF', 10000);
                    break;
                case -2:
                    // If status code is -2, user is not authenticated with Office 365
                    appendMessage('Send Mail', 'User not authenticated with Office 365', 'ALR', 10000);
                    break;
                case -3:
                    // If status code is -3, there was an error sending the mail, prompt re-login
                    appendMessage('Send Mail', "Error sending the mail. Please re-login using Office 365.", 10000);
                    console.log(message); // Log the error message
                    break;
            }
        },
        
        // On error during the request
        error: function (xhr, status, error) {
            console.error("Error sending the mail:", error);
            appendMessage('Send Mail', "Error sending the mail! Mail not sent.", 'ALR', 10000);
            
            // Redirect to the location provided in the response header
            window.location = xhr.getResponseHeader("Location");
        }
    });
}

I thoroughly reviewed the documentation and searched for similar issues online but was unable to find a solution.

I'm also concerned about this scenario, and I haven't found a solution for it and I'm afraid this is not a good idea to integrate Azure AD auth and asp.net core identity together because they share different auth scheme then it will bring an issue about how to map the users within 2 schemes, I mean when I log in with M365 account, then how the app know which account stored in your own database matches the M365 account. In the meantime, both of them use their own SDK which brings much work for custom business aims.

Pey my understanding, when we use Azure AD auth into our application and then integrate Microsoft Graph SDK, they will help us do a task like, when the GraphServiceClient is authenticated, then it will help us call MS Graph API, when it's unauthenticated or the auth is expired, SDK will help to redirect to Microsoft Identity Platform to let users sign in again and authorize the GraphServiceClient to make it work again. Therefore, this flow doesn't require us the manage the access token, however you tried to store the access token and you might need to generate new access token manually
